# Character with underbite, pointy jaw, and bug eyes

Tags: character, animation

A friend and I have been trying for about an hour to remember what character we're thinking of.  Morse, from Balto, reminded us.
[image: Morse, from Balto]

It's his underbite, with the way the lip comes to a point, the teeth sticking out, and the bug eyes.  We think it was either a dog or a fish.  Kyle, from Despicable Me, is pretty close, but has too many teeth and his mouth is too round - we also think it was 2d animation.
[image: Kyle, from Despicable Me]

The pike from Sword in the Stone is likewise similar, with the underbite and pointy teeth, but his jaw is too long, and we think it was more of a comedic relief character than the pike.
[image: Pike, from Sword in the Stone]

Overall, the character was more comic relief; we think it went around biting people a lot or something for comedic effect.  No talking.  Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Relevant meta discussion: https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4041/49.

Comment: Muttley? https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/villains/images/b/b1/Flat%2C800x800%2C075%2Cf.u2-0.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20170907132257

Answer (score 3):

My first guess would be **Butch**, typically one of the antagonists for **Droopy**:

Answer (score 2):

Here’s an extremely specific answer: could it be the giant dog at the start of the Chuck Jones-produced *Tom & Jerry* short [*Purr-chance To Dream*](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=T8S8n5ooQ-o) (1967, [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purr-Chance_to_Dream))?

[image: A screenshot of the aforementioned giant dog]

More generally, the drawing you posted reminded me of the drawing style used to draw dogs on *Tom & Jerry* when Chuck Jones was producing, and this was the best example I could find quickly. I suspect there’s others, possibly playing a more prominent role in their story, which you might be thinking of!